# leading '.' or '! ' can only appear inside a 'with' statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, text-files

I am trying to find some code which will only read in lines from a text file which have data (so non blank lines).

I came across this method:

```
fileData = File.ReadAllLines("textFile.txt").Where(i >= !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i))
```

However, I am getting the error as posted in the title and cannot seem to find much online as to what the error means and how to solve it.

If anyone can help me understand what this is that would be great.

Many thanks!

Comment: what about removing the question mark from the statement? it looks like a C# statement and not a VB one.

Comment: you've tagged this vb.net but it looks like you're writing in C#.... which is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you posted is a mixture of C# and VB.

As the question is tagged VB.NET and the title of the question refers to `With` Statements, I assume that is language you are trying to get a solution in.

The Actual VB.NET you are looking for is as follows:

```
fileData = File.ReadAllLines("textFile.txt").Where(Function(i) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(i))
```

`!` in C# is equivalent to `Not` in VB

`i =>` in C# is equivalent to `Sub(i)` or `Function(i)`

but note that pasting `=>` into Visual Studio converts it to `>=` automatically (when coding in VB)

Comment: ah yes sorry it is VB, I should have posted that in the question. Yes this has worked perfectly and has brought up no syntax errors. Thankyou very much +1!

Comment: No need to post that in the question, you have correctly tagged it which is all you need to do. The confusion lies in people mis-interpreting what you wrote

Comment: Ah ok, well it's good to know for the future anyway! Thanks again!